# How do I ignore file extensions in git regardless of case?

Tags: git, gitignore

I want to tell git to ignore e.g. jpg files regardless of how the extension is written.

e.g.

> *.jpg

should ignore

> .jpg, .JPG., .Jpg

etc.

Is that possible without telling git to ignore case altogether?

Comment: Do you want git to "work" on a case insensitive file system, or is this just for ignore purposes?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Git ignore understands glob pattern, so you can use this

```
*.[jJ][pP][gG]
```

Answer (score 20):

You can tell git to ignore case in most situations, including in your .gitignore files. All you need is:

```
git config core.ignorecase true
```

From a practical point of view, there may be trade-offs involved. The git-config(1) man page says:

```
   core.ignorecase
       If true, this option enables various workarounds to enable git to
       work better on filesystems that are not case sensitive, like FAT.
       For example, if a directory listing finds "makefile" when git
       expects "Makefile", git will assume it is really the same file, and
       continue to remember it as "Makefile".

       The default is false, except git-clone(1) or git-init(1) will probe
       and set core.ignorecase true if appropriate when the repository is
       created.
```

So, you may run into trouble if you are on a case-sensitive filesystem. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: I would not recommend this. First, as you say, this does not only make `.gitconfig` case insensitive, but essentially all of Git. Then, the config is a per-user or per-clone thing, so it won't apply to other co-developers who share `.gitconfig` with you.

Comment: I agree with @MatthieuMoy. You will absolutely, definitely, most certainly regret this -- but only after hours of debugging why your files are missing or why everything is mysteriously broken. If this is on, turn it off.

Comment: i using win10 and it seems case insensitive. I cant remember to set core.ignorecase in my repo. who can i check this?

Comment: as pointed out by @MatthieuMoy this is **not safe** in general but only when us have a case insensitive file system such as on windows.

Comment: NTFS is case-sensitive. Windows isn't. It's a subtle difference. This option is for working on FAT16, which is neither case-sensitive nor case-preserving. Imho, this is the wrong approach