# .gitignore write case insensitive

Tags: git

Is there any way to do a case insensitive .gitignore using a regex for example?
For example, inbox, Inbox, inBox, should all be ignored with a one liner in .gitignore. ?
I am writing a script to generate a .gitignore file and hence do not know what kind of pattern would be available at the client side.

Comment: Just a note: gitignore is case-sensitive. But on macOS, having the line `.DS_STORE` in gitignore ignores  the file `.DS_Store` as well for me, i.e. is case-insensitive. However, that is likely because of the default macOS filesystem's (lack of) case-sensitivity support.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11116789/2394026), gitignore file accepts glob patterns.

Following your example, you could do

```
[Ii]n[bB]ox
```

Comment: That's a glob pattern and not a regex. You can't set a regex flag in `.gitignore`

Comment: @CervEd The answer is now edited to correct this.